# Integrating a velocity function

Tags: calculus

$$2.5v_r(t)=\frac{4}{5}v_b(t)$$

If we integrate both sides, then shouldn't we get

$$0.5*2.5a_r^2(t)=0.5*\frac{4}{5}v_b^2(t)$$

How come the answer says it is instead $$2.5a_r(t)=\frac{4}{5}a_b$$

Comment: What are the subscripts?  When you integrate velocity you get position, not acceleration.  The answer key is differentiating, not integrating and seems to assume that $a_b$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship amongst velocity, acceleration, and distance are:

$d'(t) = v(t), v'(t) = a(t)$. From this you can obtain the desire formula from your particular question.